# Color DT table columns if there are matching with other columns

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to color columns if there are equal to other columns. Example

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("iris")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$iris <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(iris)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Expected output
Color Sepal.Length as green only when are equal to Sepal.width or else color as red. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I used a different data frame as the two variables you mentioned have no matching values.  Perhaps you are looking for this.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("mtcar")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  mtcars1 <- mtcars %>% mutate(match = ifelse(vs == am, 1, 0))
  
  output$mtcar <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(mtcars1, options = list(
      columnDefs = list(list(targets = 12, visible = FALSE))
    )) %>% formatStyle(
      'vs', 'match',
      color = styleInterval(c(0), c('red', 'green')),
      backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('gray', 'yellow'))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]